# Why Laravel is working without WAMP server?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I was doing some stuff on Laravel, and noticed that my **projects done by Laravel** can be executed, **without running WAMP** server. How does it working? I used to think, that to run **PHP** code, or to retrieve/write some **Data** into your **DataBase** you need to run your WAMP server. But now I don't run WAMP server and it still works fine.

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Laravel runs on a built-in server. From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick):

Typically, you may use a web server such as Apache or Nginx to serve your Laravel applications. If you are on PHP 5.4+ and would like to use PHP's built-in development server, you may use the serve Artisan command:

```
php artisan serve
```

By default the HTTP-server will listen to port 8000. However if that port is already in use or you wish to serve multiple applications this way, you might want to specify what port to use. Just add the --port argument:

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

About [Artisan CLI](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan).
Some [technical details](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) about the built-in server.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Woow, great! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

laravel has a build in server using

```
php artisan serve
```

for stoping it you should stop the cammand prompt ctrl+c